# Whitelisting domains in Content Security Policy for Angular

Tags: angular, content-security-policy, whitelist

I'm currently building a Blog application as a part of learning Angular using

- Angular 10.0.8
- QuillJS (Rich Text Editor)
- NodeJS 12.19
- Express 4.17.1
- Firebase

My problem is that after building my Angular app with ng build --prod, and serving it statically through my Express API the third party resources provided by external APIs (for example I'm using the OpenWeatherAPI for a weather Widget, and this is also sending an image) are being blocked by Content Security Policy. My Network tab confirms that they are indeed blocked.

Here are a few examples of my errors:

> Refused to load the image
> 'https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10d@2x.png' because it violates the
> following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data:".

> Refused to load the image
> 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1311006946770718720/3v5WuGyw_normal.jpg'
> because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
> "img-src 'self' data:".

> Refused to frame 'https://www.youtube.com/' because it violates the
> following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'".
> Note that 'frame-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used
> as a fallback.

I understand that I am supposed to somehow whitelist these domains so that Angular can know that they are trusted.
I have tried using the DOMSanitizer to convert the url sent from the backend to a safeResourceUrl but nothing changed.
I tried implementing my own meta tags (code blow) noth in the static index.html generated by ng build, as well as the index.html in the angular project but it seems like it only recognized the 'self' part and ignored the urls.

```
<meta 
http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
content="img-src 'self' https://openweathermap.org/ https://pbs.twimg.com/" />
```

I also have implemented custom CORS headers on the backend as well as helmetjs, but tinkering with those didn't yield any result. Commenting out my entire Helmet config didn't help at all. Code for my CORS as it is without changes regarding my problem below.

```
// CORS Implementation
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  let origin = req.headers.origin || req.headers.referer;

  if (origin && origin.match(/localhost/gi)) {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    res.setHeader(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
      "OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE"
    );
    res.setHeader(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "Content-Type, Accept, APPKEY, withCredentials"
    );
  }

  if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    res.status(200).json({});
  } else {
    next();
  }
};
```

My question is, where exactly should I be whitelisting these 3rd party domains in my Angular application? What is the best way to go about this without breaking the application, or opening it to attacks from places that aren't on this list of domains.
I wasn't sure if providing any code from the actual project would help, but I added it on a separate repo just in case. I have two files on gitignore that I'm using to setup the Firebase apiKeys and such, as well as the Twitter API setup so unfortunately it wont work without them.

> https://github.com/AlamoFiteCat/cheesed-blog

Thank you in advance for the answers.

Comment: I think there are 2 issues. 1st) You mistaken CPS with CORS. That is not the same. 2) As a result you didn't try adding CSP to the Server. The Issue is server defined CSP goes over clientside CSP. Your not working clientside CSP could be explained by a serverside CSP, maybe a default value somewhere. Maybe this link helps https://ponyfoo.com/articles/content-security-policy-in-express-apps

Comment: Yes, this is definitely it! Thanks! I really did have them mixed up. I hadn't set up a CSP on my backend at all, so now I implemented it in the form of a middleware. It works sort of weird, because I did something like this

 res.set(
    "Content-Security-Policy",
    "img-src 'self' http://openweathermap.org/"
  );

and for some reason it completely ignores this config, but it fixed the same error I was getting for the frame for the embedded YT file. I'll dig around and post a solution as soon as I find it. I'll also try to do it via helmet too.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I managed to fix it with the help of @MoxxiManagarm
My problem was definitely in the backend.
The issue was that even though I had already installed Helmet, it was terribly configured. I played around with it until I had a functional config. The errors that were popping up in the console were also helpful in determining how to assemble the CSP.
This is my CSP configuration that fixed it for me.

```
app.use(
  helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
    directives: {
      "default-src": ["'self'"],
      "connect-src": ["'self'", "http://numbersapi.com/"],
      "style-src": ["'self'", "https: 'unsafe-inline'"],
      "font-src": ["'self'", "https: data:"],
      "script-src": ["'self'"],
      "object-src": ["'none'"],
      "frame-src": ["'self'", "https://www.youtube.com/"],
      "img-src": [
        "'self'",
        "http://openweathermap.org/",
        "https://pbs.twimg.com/",
      ],
    },
  })
);
```

Thanks again!

Comment: You use: `http://numbersapi.com/` in connect-src and `http://openweathermap.org/` in img-src. Be careful: access `http:` sources on `https:` pages will cause mixed content blocking, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content